# How to set the handler of a child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the onChange of Select component that I built.
My 2 components are Profile and Select. 
I don't know why But never comes into the handler.

My code (Profile):

```
@Profile = React.createClass
  handleGender: ->
   console.log('here we go')
  render: ->
    React.createElement Select, { options: @props.gender, onChange: @handleGender }
```

Select Component

```
@Select = React.createClass
 render: ->
  select
   className: "select"
   for v, k in @props.options
    option
      key:       k
      value:     v
      className: "option"
      v
```

I've tried several things but it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like Profile.render is inside handleGender.

Comment: Sorry it was a bad identation in the question but in my code is ok. I've edited here.

Comment: I think the onChange needs to be on the select element itself, not on the react component containing the select element.

Comment: Yes! was that! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @Sigfried you have to forward the `onChange` prop if you want the final `select` event to pop up to the first component :

```
@Select = React.createClass
 render: ->
  select
   className: "select"
   onChange: @props.onChange 
   for v, k in @props.options
    option
      key:       k
      value:     v
      className: "option"
      v
```

*As a side note, it is generally not advised to use an already existing HTML component name for a custom component, as it can be confusing. If you name your component, let's say, `GenderSelect`, it will be a lot more obvious that this is a custom component, which does not come with an `onChange` event out of the box.*